# Is the TV show The Wombles on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The Wombles has a few fantasy elements:

A main character from a made up race.

A setting that is basically invented. Wimbledon Common is nothing like the setting in the Wombles.

As such would it be  on topic?

Comment: Do we really need to ask this for every show?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Possibly? http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9909/do-we-have-to-ask-if-all-these-works-are-on-topic-or-not

Comment: @Skooba top answer seems to say no.

Comment: If the Wombles are on-topic, then you open the door to *Willo The Wisp*, *Bill & Ben* and *The Teletubbies* to name but three.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wombles), there are a considerable number of canon elements that would put the show firmly on-topic on SFF:SE, notably that a number of supposedly fictional animals (Yetis and Nessies) are in fact womble sub-species as well as the presence of magic and telepathy.

> Several sub-species of Womble are revealed throughout the books: the
>   Loch Ness Monster is actually part of a clan of water Wombles and the
>   yeti of the Himalayas are giant snow-white Wombles. Wombles have a
>   sixth sense which allows them to sense green spaces and wildlife; this
>   is first mentioned in the Wandering Wombles but developed to a keen
>   long range telepathic sense by Dalai Gartok Womble in 'The Wombles Go
>   Round The World'.

Comment: Maybe so, but none of these subspecies of Womble ever appeared, or were even mentioned, in the television show.